# Delete in two tables gives errors

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I must eliminate the technicians called "Oscar", who did repairs in the
year 2010.

I must first delete the repairs they performed, then remove the technicians called "Oscar"'. I do this in two statements:

```
DELETE FROM Reparacion  WHERE cuit_tec IN(SELECT Tec.cuit
            FROM Tecnico Tec 
            WHERE Tec.nombre like 'oscar%'
            AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                    FROM Reparacion Rep
                    WHERE Rep.cuit_tec = Tec.cuit 
                    AND Fecha BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31'));
```

and

```
DELETE FROM 
    Tecnico AS Tec 
WHERE 
    Nombre like 'oscar%' AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
                1 
            FROM 
                Reparacion AS Rep 
            WHERE 
                Rep.Cuit_tec = Tec.Cuit AND 
                Fecha BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-12-31');
```

This throws error messages:

```
"Error Code: 1093. You can not specify target table 'Repair' for update in FROM clause"
"Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the Manual That Corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS Tec WHERE Name = 'oscar' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM R ' at line 2 "
```

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9438d

Comment: Please edit your question, it is ambiguous. Do you want to remove the Oscar technicians who *only* had repairs in 2010? Do you want to remove the Oscar technicians and their 2010 repairs, which will leave you with 2011 etc repair done by Oscar no longer pointing to a living ;-) technician?

Comment: If you only want to remove the Oscars who *only* had 2010 repairs wou will have to create a temporary table that selects those Oscars - then remove the appropriate repairs and technicians based on that temp table, then remove the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't error here:

```
WHERE 
    Nombre like= 'oscar%' AND
```

Gotta be `Nombre like 'oscar%' AND`